# Regex rule for .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Who can help me with regex rule?

If visited page is `https://example.com/shop/product` then I need to redirect user to `https://example.com/product`, but if visited page is `https://example.com/shop/page/2` I need to do nothing.

There is possibility, that user landed on `https://example.com/shop/category/child-category/product` and for this example I need to redirect to `https://example.com/category/child-category/product`

I have already wrote this rule: `RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`, but this rule redirects user from this page if he is in second or other pages.

Comment: ok but then how do you define for which URLs you want redirects and for which you don't?

Comment: If there is ```/shop/page/2``` then I don't need to redirect, but if user landed on page which is ```/shop/category/product```, then I need to redirect to ```/category/product```. So rule need to check if there is keyword ```page``` then do nothing, but if there is then do redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead condition like this:

```bash
RewriteRule ^shop/(?!page/)(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

`(?!page/)` is a negative lookahead condition that will fail the match if `page/` appears after `shop/`

Comment: It works, but I have forgot to mention that there ar possibility, that user landed on ```https://example.com/shop/category/child-category/product``` and for this example your rule doesn't redirect to ```https://example.com/category/child-category/product```

Comment: ok try my updated rule now.